# Is Careers for system administrators, too?

Tags: support, jobs

As per subject: I can't understand from the FAQ is the Careers site is only programmer-related or if it can be used by/for sysadmins. I suppose it would make sense for (serious) employers to look for professionals on Server Fault other than Stack Overflow...

Comment: Well, there is http://careers.serverfault.com/jobs, but it doesn't look quite the same.

Comment: In practice it will [no longer does](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/271121/242800)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary focus of the Careers services at this point is on programmers and programming jobs. The job listings are "syndicated" both on Stack Overflow and Server Fault because of the overlap in the audience and also because it's not uncommon for system administration jobs to be posted by employers also hiring programmers.

As ServerFault.com continues to grow, we'd like to eventually augment our service offering to give the system administration community a careers place of its own as well.