# Does Careers support system administration jobs now?

Tags: support, jobs

I'm following up to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82331/is-careers-for-system-administrators-too) as I've seen recently lots of job postings on Carees for system administration jobs. Has there been any "official" endorsement of this, or have just those postings appeared there on their own?

Also, since I have pretty good reputation on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/users/6352/massimo), if Careers now supports system administration jobs, how can I get an invitation?

Comment: @Adam: done, thank you very much.

Comment: Wow, thanks Adam. That's a really nice thing to share :-)

Comment: All my invites are gone.  Good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi, there is nothing official but yes of course sysadmin job listings are welcome. We advertise them on ServerFault, and have a [page](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/sysadmin) for them.