# Front page does not show indication for bounty when it enters grace period

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-bydesign, bounties, homepage

I was just browsing the [front page of MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) when I noticed [a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271121/please-don-t-make-careers-developers-only) that I remembered having a bounty, doesn't have a bounty indication anymore:

> [image]

Puzzled (since I was quite sure it didn't end yet) I entered the question and the bounty is still there, though in grace period:

> [image]

Now it's not just few minutes delay. It's 24 hours of not seeing bounty indication. Can there be such indication, even when bounty is in grace period? Same applies to the [featured tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/?tab=featured), which is not showing the question.

Comment: I mean…that's kind of the point, right? Otherwise the bounty length is just completely extended one day, there'd be no difference to the "grace period". Strictly speaking it doesn't really make technical sense answers within the grace period can be awarded the bounty, but it's practical for the person granting the bounty (who just wants a good answer) I suppose.

Comment: @Tim good point, I never really figured what the bounty grace period means. But the fact is the bounty creator can still award it, so by all means, the question still got a bounty and new answers can stil get it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tim Stone nails it in the comments:

> I mean…that's kind of the point, right? Otherwise the bounty length is just completely extended one day, there'd be no difference to the "grace period". Strictly speaking it doesn't really make technical sense answers within the grace period can be awarded the bounty, but it's practical for the person granting the bounty (who just wants a good answer) I suppose.

The grace period is there to allow more time for the bounty to be awarded.