# The notification for the bounty award within 24 hours can be improved

Tags: discussion, bounties, notifications

In the current message one can read:

> Your bounty on question "..." is completed. You must award it to an answer within 24 hours.

To be clear this is the message that appears if I didn't give my bounty to an answer within the bounty period (7 days, if I am not mistaken).

I think this message is faulty because the bounty is not completed (I did not give the bounty to anyone, and I still can award it to an answer).

What I am trying to convey is that the first sentence is somewhat contradictory to the second sentence.

Here's my suggestion:

> You should award the bounty of the question "..." to an answer within 24 hours. This is the last reminder.

Additionally a link to how bounties are automatically awarded if the user chooses to not award it could prove useful.

Comment: This should be a change affecting all communities I believe.

Comment: I believe what "your bounty is completed" actually means in that message is that [the question will no longer show up as featured](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/272475). But yes, I can see how that could be misinterpreted.

Answer (score 2):

With the answer given by @Anthony and the comment given by@Ilmari it seems the community still wants to portray that the question is no longer **featured**. I would then suggest the following notification:

> You opened a bounty on "..." 7 days ago. The question is no longer
>   featured. Please award the bounty to an answer within 24 hours
>   otherwise it might be [automatically
>   awarded](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/bounty).

Answer (score 1):

The 24 hours is regarding to the grace period for your bounty thus the change should actually be:

> Your bounty's seven days on the question "..." are over. Please award your bounty within the 24 hour grace period or your bounty will be automatically awarded if there is an answer that [met the standards necessary](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/bounty).

Comment: As a somewhat regular SE user I could live with that message but I still find two problems in it. What is over is not the bounty but the featuring of the question. If I were a less frequent user I would like to have less technical Jargon such as `grace period` or `standards necessary`.

Comment: Thus there is a link straight to the Help Center article on bounties