# Please STOP trying to convert ! to ? on all sites and not just the orginal trilogy?

Tags: feature-request, title, quality-filter

Some days ago, I wrote this [feature request removal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/271121/242800).

But as peoples are pointing it out, employers will still be encouraged to post non‑developers jobs on the new system. So I wanted to add`in practice !`in the title.

This wasn’t a problem for [that closed earlier post](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/8542/please-don-t-make-careers-programmers-only-in-practice).
However, each time I correct [the title here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/271121/242800), the ! mark is converted to a ? mark.

Even if this is the normal wanted behaviour, then there is still a bug because nothing prevented me to title [this post](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/8542/please-don-t-make-careers-programmers-only-in-practice) `Please don’t make Careers programmers only in practice!`. If it’s the normal behaviour then it should have been titled to`Please don’t make Careers programmers only in practice?`like [my request here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/271121/242800).
So 1 of the 2 cases isn’t the normal behaviour.

There were a [feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/115327/242800) with a[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed). But as the network evolved, it currently only concerns the original trilogy.
Moreover, a post title ending by a `!`isn’t a strong signal of a bad title in the case of a[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request). So it’s safe to add an exception when[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)is used.

**Please extend [this feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/115327/242800) to all sites !**

Comment: The bug is not blocking the "!" which is fine IMO, just the fact it's converted to a question mark for some reason.

Comment: @ShadowWizard : could you re examine your close vote with my edit please. Though you probably can’t see [that closed post](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/8542/please-don-t-make-careers-programmers-only-in-practice) because you don’t have an account on Server Fault.

Comment: This particular feature can lead to some serious confusion when you ask a question on Math.SE about n!

Comment: @MadScientist : the point is it does not append [here](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/8542/please-don-t-make-careers-programmers-only-in-practice).

Comment: I examined my close vote and it still stands, it's MSE so any bug report is expected to be relevant to  all sites, otherwise it's off topic to begin with.

Comment: @ShadowWizard : I’m not aware of a single meta site dedicated to just Server Fault ; Super User ; and Stack Overflow.

Comment: @ShadowWizard : I don’t think posting this 3 three time is the correct way. Notice [this feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/115327/242800) is only posted one time and not closed, despite the [tag:status-completed] concerning only the original trilogy. I’d rather think it should be extended to all sites.

Comment: not a dupe for me. Even forgetting than the alleged dupe is a support question that has been closed as a dupe of a feature request for some odd reason, considering this one a dupe of the original feature request still seem off to me. There was a request to change the behavior of the "auto fix" - it was done but only on a subset of sites. The user is asking to extend to consider extending the fix, and I don't see any other reasonable way to post this request...  Unless we claim that the original fix should be taken as a prof that the staff don't want to extend the fix everywhere.

Comment: @SPArchaeologist : as you can see in comments above, ShadowWizard *(and probably others)* thinks because this concerns the original trilogy and  because there were a similar feature request, that post should be asked 3 times on the meta sites of Server Fault ; Super User ; and Stack Overflow. Not to mention closing as duplicate should be done against answered posts. I also got [that case](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/8542/203649) recently.

Comment: @user2284570 As i said, there are at least three different problems: 1) **if** you are a dupe, you are a dupe of [Stop rewriting trailing exclamation marks as question marks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115327/stop-rewriting-trailing-exclamation-marks-as-question-marks), not the one currently linked (that is a support question and imho didn't deserve the dupe closure).

Comment: 2) you are a dupe only if the original question should be read as *"Please fix everywhere - No, we will never apply the fix to all the sites"* and again, imho this is not the case. An user asked for a change, they enabled it on a subset of sites and now you are asking them if they can extend it to other sites. This wasn't ever asked explicitly: again, not a dupe for me.

Comment: and 3) I don't get the "it is off topic here because it is expected to be about all the sites" part used to justify this post to be offtopic. You ask **Please extend this feature to all sites !** -- what sites are left out of the topic? The ones *that already have this???*. If I got this right, then it means that it is also offtopic to ask here to enable the dice service from RPG on every site because RPG already has it... Seem weird to me, I hope I got it wrong.

Comment: @SPArchaeologist I know this, I voted to re open. I also got many feature request closed against support question over the network http://meta.serverfault.com/q/8542/203649. I posted a question about the behaviour and get it answered that support question and features requests about the same topic makes duplicates, so I'm starting to wonder.

Comment: In your edit, please explain why it is not a duplicate instead of just stating you disagree. @user2284570

Comment: @SPArchaeologist I can’t see what sentences I can add. Any ideas for the previous comment?

Comment: @user2284570 - do you mind if I edit that in the text at the end of the question? I think the whole point is that the only post that you can be considered a dupe is the original feature-request, not the support request that the closers have oddly decided to point to. Also, the original feature request was completed by just implementing it on the trilogy sites, and you are asking a change to the implemented solution. How asking for a change to the currently implemented solution *can be a dupe of the original request for the currently implemented solution* I still fail to understand.

Comment: @SPArchaeologist yes, please suggest it.

Comment: Somewhat related hint (because space-before-trailing-punctuation will also be autoremoved): French is the only major language that likes to put a space before “double punctuation”. It’s totally uncommon in English (or Spanish, or German, or Russion, …) and looks very strange.

Comment: @chirlu : we don’t put normal space before double punctuation. And there are several types according`?` `«` `»` `;` `!`or`:`.

Comment: The point is that in English (etc.), *no* space is used.

Comment: @user2284570 - I was able to edit you question [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271121/please-don-t-make-careers-developers-only-in-pratice) to include the exclamation point. It is strange - wasn't this the one that kept switching the '!' to '?' for you??

Comment: @SPArchaeologist yes it was. I think I may found why: can you try it in the french way? I mean with a narrow non breaking space before thr punctuation mark.