# I can’t access many Stack Exchange sites. Please fix your CloudFlare CDN

Tags: support, cdn, cloudflare

I’m unable to get any Stack Overflow, Super User, Server Fault, and security.stackexchange pages displayed correctly if I’m logged in *(maybe this list is incomplete)*.

[image]

After looking at my debugging tools, I found the CSS fails to load correctly, because I’m getting a 409 response.

[image]

More information:

```
tracert cdn.sstatic.net

Détermination de l’itinéraire vers cdn.sstatic.net [104.16.106.204]
avec un maximum de 30 sauts :

  1     4 ms     3 ms     1 ms  neufbox [192.168.1.1]
  2    40 ms    41 ms    42 ms  44pir1-r0b0-1.dip.gaoland.net [84.96.176.43]
  3    42 ms    39 ms    40 ms  117.178.96.84.rev.sfr.net [84.96.178.117]
  4    40 ms    41 ms    38 ms  110.178.96.84.rev.sfr.net [84.96.178.110]
  5    54 ms    46 ms    50 ms  cloudflare.franceix.net [37.49.237.49]
  6    46 ms    47 ms    49 ms  cdn.sstatic.net [104.16.106.204]

Itinéraire déterminé.
```

Hopefully, Meta Stack Exchange works, but I can’t reply to comments on the targeted web sites. Please fix this!!!

Comment: In which part of the world are you located?

Comment: Concerning the question mark instead of the exclamation make in the title. Please support this [feature-request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/272800/242800).

Comment: @Quill : just traceroute my public ɪᴘ address which is in the second screenshot.

Comment: CDN problems are most often caused by localised issues with CDNs, that's what they're for. Knowing which part of the world you're located will help determine the source of the issue.

Comment: @Oded : anyway, as you can see it on the second screenshost, the issue is with CloudFlare.

Comment: @user2284570 See the edit to my answer. If you can get the `dig` output as well, that'd be great.

Comment: @Quill : stop trying to change the question title : Not all Stack Exchange sites are concerned. And writing internet without starting with an upper case letter is valid in ᴜᴋ English.

Comment: People are trying to help by improving your grammar and readability. Too bad you don't accept it and keep reverting their correct changes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We aren't using Cloudflare anymore as of a few weeks ago. I realize that's what the screenshot says... but something on your end isn't resolving cdn.sstatic.net correctly.

Can you post a traceroute output from your machine to cdn.sstatic.net?

(Correction... apparently what would actually be helpful is the output from `dig +trace cdn.sstatic.net`. I don't know much about getting it installed/running on Windows myself, but there are some [instructions here](http://www.danesparza.net/2011/05/using-the-dig-dns-tool-on-windows-7/)).

Comment: Maybe, an ɪꜱᴘ ᴅɴꜱ cache error ? I’ll check this…

Comment: No CF? Good... but what are you using now instead?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Fastly

Comment: lol, I [should have remembered](http://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/280285/revisions). :-)

Comment: @AdamLear :Ok I just put the fallback ᴅɴꜱ server as the primary in the /etc/resolv.conf of my ᴀᴅꜱʟ router. Don’t know what is triggering this.`dig +trace cdn.sstatic.net`won’t be any help know.

Comment: @user2284570 Does everything work fine with the fallback DNS?

Comment: @AdamLear : yes it is.