Testing a new version of Stack Overflow Jobs
Update on October 10, 2024:
As of today, Stack Overflow Jobs will be hosted on stackoverflowjobs.com. If you visit stackoverflow.jobs it will reroute to the new domain. Along with making this change, we have also fixed several issues noted on the Known Issues post.

Update on May 8th, 2024
Stack Overflow Jobs is now live. If you notice any bugs or other issues with the job site please report them on this separate post.

I am happy to announce that we are experimenting with bringing back a version of Stack Overflow Jobs!
The first iteration of Stack Overflow Jobs brought a lot of value to the developer community. At its peak, it served legions of job seekers resulting in roughly 6 million yearly job searches, 2 million yearly “apply” clicks, and above industry average application submission rates.
Many community members reported a strong preference for using Stack Overflow Jobs in their job search because of our unique focus on developer needs, and were truly disappointed to see it go.
But unfortunately, the business model of the feature was not sustainable for Stack because of the investment it would have taken to make it competitive with other job sites. However, we are aware of how much users liked it, and how many people found a great job through it. In the last few years, we have heard repeatedly from community members that they want it back.
We heard you, and we are delighted to announce that we are introducing a new version of Stack Overflow Jobs, crafted in partnership with Indeed, a leading global hiring platform. By partnering with Indeed, we believe we have found a solution that allows us to provide a best-in-class job site experience while continuing to focus on our strength – the developer community.
What’s being tested
Stack Overflow Jobs will be launching in the coming weeks as an initial test (we will update this post once the experiment is live, so stay tuned). At first, this will be only available in the US. Through the first phase of this experiment we will be looking to get answers to some of these questions:

Does the new Stack Overflow Jobs allow us to bring the same degree of value to technical job seekers as the prior version did?

Does this business model enable us to expand to more markets so we can serve more job seekers?

Can we create the long-term sustainability needed to continue building upon and improving this feature?


We know job searching can be stressful and time consuming. Half the battle is finding quality jobs that are a good match for your skills and interests, before even starting the application process. We believe that by combining the unique strengths of Stack Overflow, including our dedication to the developer community, and Indeed’s volume of quality tech jobs, we can help developers and other technical job seekers find their next great opportunity via a curated, tech focused job site.
We see this as just the beginning, with hopes of proving out this partnership model to expand in both product features and functionally, as well as more markets outside the US.
How it works
The new Stack Overflow Jobs, powered by Indeed, will be hosted on its own domain (stackoverflowjobs.com), linked from the left navigation on Stack Overflow and technical Stack Exchange sites (the same group of sites where you see ‘Companies’ in the left navigation, though to be clear ‘Companies’ and ‘Jobs’ remain separate features).
The job site will showcase thousands of technical job listings in the US. Use keyword searches to find jobs that are a great fit for your interests and experience. In order to apply for a job, hit the “apply” button and you will be redirected to the posting on Indeed, where you can submit your application. No personal data about users is shared between Stack Overflow and Indeed.

We are taking measures to ensure that the listings that populate Stack Overflow Jobs will be high quality and highly relevant to the Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange technical community. However in the event that something off-topic slips through the cracks, we want to get it corrected as soon as possible. See the help center article here with more information.
Feedback
We are considering this an experiment with bringing back a feature that previously brought a lot of value to the site. As we learn, we will evaluate growth and expansion opportunities. This may include revisiting features from the original version of Stack Overflow Jobs and/or building new ones, to continue helping technologists on a job search journey.
Our goal is to create a job site experience that developers and other technical job seekers love. Let us know how we can do that!
When thinking about searching for your next technical role, what pieces of information or features would be most useful for you?
Do you have feedback about your experience with the original Stack Overflow Jobs? What did you like or dislike?
What are the most important things for us to keep in mind as we iterate on this experiment?

For once sharing datas between SO and Indeed on a voluntary basis would have been useful, yet "No personal data about users is shared between Stack Overflow and Indeed.". I take this means SO Jobs will just be redirect links to indeed with no added value on top, am I missing something ?

@Sasha "... will be hosted on its own domain". Assuming it's not a subdomain of stackexchange.com / stackoverflow.com, any chance you could add the domain to this list of domains?

@Tensibai I guess it could have some value to SO Inc. in that they can get telemetry on what people click on and so get data about jobs their users are interested in, but I don't think that's what you were asking about (value to us- the users)

you probably want a remote work toggle, too, in addition to those two search boxes

@starball yes, I was alluding that for once, giving consent for data sharing would have value for us and SO too. I get they didn't want to open this box, but that 's something I had asked the community about in their shoes.

That was quite the rollercoaster, going from "Awesome!" to "... so it's basically just an ad for an unpleasant job search site"  . As much as the new title is better, it would probably make more sense to just call it was it is "Launching a new ad for indeed".

@dan1st: its here because of" technical Stack Exchange sites "  so there's likely to be a link on the other 2 trilogy sites (server fault and super user) and others. Its not SO only

@KevinB “Remote” can be typed into the title/keyword field (not the location field) to search for remote jobs.

Please add an option to hide this from the sidebar so I don't accidentally visit indeed.  I make a habit of NEVER visiting Indeed.  One of the reasons I never use Indeed is the fake jobs.

@Ramhound clicking the link to SO Jobs from the left sidebar will not take you to Indeed. The job site will be hosted on its own, separate domain (not SO or Indeed). Once there you will only be redirected to Indeed if you were to hit the "apply" button.

So if I understand that right, SO jobs is just showing jobs that I could just go onto indeed and look at anyway… isn’t that like going to a StackOverflow clone to find an answer?

I don't understand how this is different to going to Indeed. What's the advantage of this?

@RobGrant Take it as just an ad, where StackOverflow sold rights to license their brand for hopefully a tonne of money to Indeed. The idea is that the StackOverflow brand has a certain amount of trust, whilst Indeed really needs that trust, so for StackOverflow they liquidate a bit of the trust into money. As long as they mark it as an ad I really don't mind.

@Sasha, users might not be redirected to Indeed, and the domain may be wholly unique... But will that website be running on Stack's servers or Indeed's servers? Which company is operating the infrastructure it runs on? Presumably the new site is just a Stack-Branded website that makes all the same API calls as the regular Indeed site?

@cocomac Yes, the new domain will be added to this community wiki when the feature goes live, under the category “Related domains, not needed for viewing/using the regular Q/A sites.”

I still want an option to remove the ad for Indeed on the sidebar. It’s appearing on every community,  it just limited, to Stack Overflow.

Where/how are we to leave feedback for the new jobs page?  Maybe I'm missing something but I don't see any feedback specific links mentioned here, and I don't see any feedback specific links at the new jobs page.  Or are we supposed to dump feedback in these comments?  I'll start ... how about some basic filters ... number of days 'back' to search (eg, last 24 hours, last 3 days, last week) ... ability to order results by date or relevancy; also, how about search instructions (boolean search?); I'm not interested in scrolling through 20 pages of hits to find jobs listed in the  last 7 days.

ok, more feedback ... lousy search engine; searching on a single low-hit item - sybase - brings up page after page after page after page of hits with most of the listed jobs containing not a single instance of the string sybase; sooooo, how about finding a search engine that actually works

@markp-fuso users can continue to leave feedback about SO Jobs on this post, I am still monitoring it. Or if there are bugs to report we are collecting those on this secondary post which is also linked i in the update at the top of the post above.

I tried it and it's awful.  The UI is badly implemented and broken. The quality of jobs and the search is abysmal. It's like you combined the worst of indeed with the worst of stack overflow. Sorry, 0/10, will avoid.

Would be nice if it wasn't limited to US only, at least in a sense, so that people outside US can create resume and download it. So far not very useful.

I feel like this might be missing the point, the core thing we liked about SO Jobs.  We don't want to go to yet another job site and "create an Indeed profile".  We want our existing SO profile to be the core of our experience, so it can be showcased to recruiters as a first class part of our identity on the platform.

Basically making Careers back https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/271121

Yeah nobody would go around creating profiles at various sites unless they were actively looking for jobs. So this will rule out a whole lot of candidates, namely those who aren't actively looking, but may be interested in job offers still. Missing the whole point of SO integration indeed.

This is useful feedback about what made the prior version of SO Jobs valuable to users, and which aspects of that would be meaningful to incorporate into this new approach. Our first task during this phase is validating the potential in this experiment (based on the questions I listed in the “What's being tested” section). So while this initial test will not include an integration with users’ existing SO profiles, this is something we are open to working into future iterations of the feature.

@Sasha will Jobs postings be included in the data dumps?

@perigon no, they will not be included because they are hosted on a separate domain.

"will not include an integration with users’ existing SO profiles"
And therefore... Just use the Indeed app. Integration with SO profiles should have been the #1 consideration when considering this partnership. IMO

The only thing I'm annoyed about with this announcement is the title. SO Jobs isn't coming back, this isn't SO Jobs. If you want a partnership with Indeed and think that will be profitable, great! but this isn't what SO Jobs was. It isn't different from every other job search network (it's literally just phoned in from another job search network!)
I don't really understand yet why I would use this over just going to indeed. Surely I'd rather see all of the job listings relevant to my searches rather than just the ones SO has deemed worthy of my viewing.

You're right. The original title on this post was not an accurate description of what the post is actually about. I updated it with something that I think is a better fit, and which is the same title I used in the post giving the mods a heads up about this in their private team a few weeks back.

Basically making Careers back https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/271121

Why ? Because Indeed have a lot of fake proposal and have a low answer rate

Indeed is a horrible company.  I have no idea the reason anyone would partner with them.

@Ramhound It'$ a my$tery

"Surely I'd rather see all of the job listings relevant to my searches rather than just the ones SO has deemed worthy of my viewing." This assumes that Indeed does have all the job listings relevant to your searches and does deem them worthy of your viewing. I do not know if that is true. In my experience, Indeed has a rather low signal-to-noise ratio.

@MikeNakis it does, however, if i go to indeed i can see the ML Engineer job for a reputable international business 10 minutes away from me, where as if i look for it on SO jobs it doesn't exist and there's no jobs in the entire state.


But unfortunately, the business model of the feature was not
sustainable for Stack because of the investment it would have taken to
make it competitive with other job sites.

The primary advantage of the Stack Overflow job site was that most employment agencies and HR departments did not know about it, so when a job was posted it was likely that had been posted by a developer who was part of the team you would be going to work on.
Likewise unlike other job sites, posting a job on Stack Overflow did not lead to 100s of phone calls from agents offering candidates.
Hence it would lose all value from being "competitive with other job sites".

Not my experience. I once ended up advertising jobs at SO without even knowing it, the employment agency had some sort of online advertising package and so the advert ended up on SO as part of that, without me as the recruiter/SO user/part of team member even being aware. Then of course SO Jobs had godawful candidate matching, so it was pretty useless. "We can see that you are an embedded systems C programming in Sweden, so how about moving to Germany, learning German and then starting up a new career as web developer in Java?" Err... I'll pass.

@Lundin in the "good days" employment agency where not allowed on stackoverflow jobs site.   Then at about the same time that "be nice" replaced quality questions it chaged.

It used to be the case that on the old stackoverflow jobs, you'd apply and instantly talk to an actual tech guy and a lot of the time you apply you get a response as opposed to these other sites like Indeed, Seek, etc where there is a lot of spam, recruiters and ignored applications. Stackoverflow jobs was working amazingly until one day it disappeared. I'm wondering if there is something like the old stackoverflow jobs, for the moment the best i have found is LinkedIn, but it doesn't seem to work as well

I'm unclear exactly what Stack Overflow is offering here... Doesn't the image you share look the exact same as the existing Indeed UI with a different logo?


Stack Overflow is offering its brand (and thus trust, which Indeed badly needs) in return for money. The point isn't to provide something of value to the users, the point is that Indeed is happy to pay a bunch of money to advertise on StackOverflow.

@DavidMulder - that’s interesting because I’d assumed it was indeed that was offering its brand. Trust hasn’t been a thing on StackOverflow for a long time now

@Sayse There's a difference between "trust by the SE Community" and "Trust by the general developer Community". I would say that developers do still trust SO quite a bit.

I think the question of "How is this different from searching on Indeed?" is a big one. How do I, as a job seeker or a hiring manager, get benefit from Indeed Overflow compared to cutting out the middleware and going straight to Indeed?

This is just an initial test of a new version of Stack Overflow Jobs, during which we are focused on validating the potential of this feature (based on the questions I listed in the “What's being tested” section). So for now, it is basically a dynamic, searchable list of technical job openings, which will be linked from SO and technical SE sites.

In the future we hope to build out more unique functionality that will increase the site’s value to users who are seeking new job opportunities. With that in mind, we appreciate all the feedback on this post so far about what specifically users would find the most useful.

@Sasha - I hope thats the case but lets remember - "The effort it would take us to truly differentiate in this space is not one we could justify"

@Sayse For some people, yes, "trust hasn't been a thing...for quite some time now." But for others, our level of trust is not as low as yours. For example, the whole Monca thing, though not handled well, was handled correctly in the end according to many of us. (Remember, the issue was not over Monica just calling people "they" when she didn't know what pronoun that the person preferred, but that she said explicitly she would refuse to use "she" even after being informed that that was that person's preferred pronoun.)

@cjs - I guess in the end it comes down to Would you board a plane safety-tested by the SOCorp leadership team?

@Sayse Can we send the SOCorp leadership team on that plane?

@dan1st - We can ask them but they'll do what they want anyway

Then no. Again, I was speaking based on the info given above.

the way that this is different from Indeed is the search is somehow worse. on Indeed if I search "JavaScript" I get JavaScript jobs. if I search on whatever this is I get Java jobs, UX designer jobs, C# jobs, you name it. utterly worthless

One thing that made the old Stack Overflow Jobs unique is the "Developer Story" where people could have some sort of public CV.
I think that might be one thing many people liked that feature yet I haven't seen anything about that in this announcements.
Are there any plans to have something similar to that?

Developer Story is not going to be included in this initial experiment, but we know how well loved that feature was. I can’t make any promises at this stage, but it is something that is on the top of our list to consider reviving in future iterations.

Is there a possibility (From Indeed's side - I am not asking for a promise!) that such a Developer Story recreation gets connected with the new Stack Overflow Jobs?

The Developer Story and the ability to generate and download a CV from it was a great feature. I got lots of positive feedback on it, WRT layout, etc.

Developer Story was my only CV for many years. That's the main thing I miss. I don't understand what business reason there was for removing that feature. How much would it really cost to just turn it back on and leave it alone? I don't currently have a CV and have gotten by with just using LinkedIn. I dread the idea of learning some other tool for creating a new CV. If you don't want to continue running it as a service, could you at least open source it?


Do you have feedback about your experience with the original Stack
Overflow Jobs? What did you like or dislike?

As a C-language programmer, Stack Overflow Jobs was the best job search experience by far.  I could actually search for C programming jobs!  Try that on any other job search site (including Indeed) and you'll get a few results buried in an endless sea of C++ and C# jobs that aren't even remotely relevant.  Job search engines don't do well with one-letter query terms, and they typically straight-up ignore non-alphanumeric characters.  I'd waste literal hours digging through results to find one or two that were actually relevant to my search terms.  Or, I could go to SO Jobs and do the same thing in 15 seconds.
If you're making a programmer-focused job site, being able to accurately filter by programming language should be a must-have feature.  Companies posting jobs should have to specify the languages involved, preferably by using something akin to the tag chooser on Stack Overflow instead of just free-form text entry.  Bonus points if you have separate categories for "required" and "nice to have" languages.

This is a primary concern, for me: Search filters need to work exactly. Google's focus on PageRank has led to a situation where most search tools no longer obey strict Boolean -NOT filters; some even substitute more common terms in place of an "exact quote"! Precision filtering is more essential than ever, & widely neglected. "C " should return only C & not "C++ " etc.

Update: Thanks for hearing the feedback about this question's original title and fixing it.

I am pleased to learn that you are acting on community feedback. I want to learn more about how the new Stack Overflow Jobs will work.
Like others, I'm "annoyed" by the marketing style used on some Meta SE post titles. I understand that there are perspectives on this being considered a regular business practice. I know there are marketing reasons to reuse online service names, in this case, Stack Overflow Jobs, but you are not bringing back something; you are just reusing a service name. Google has done the same, even using the same name simultaneously (a recent case is using "Workspace" as a product and feature name).
Stack Overflow has been walking away from its roots. While we should accept that they are a business dealing with complex goals in complex times, I think that it's fair to expect them to keep Meta Stack Exchange as a place leaning closer to what is expected about post titles in the Stack Exchange Network: They should be a summary of the post content and free of "click bait" like writing style.
I think that partnerships are good; I just hope that this will bring back the best features of the original Stack Overflow Jobs.

You make good points about the original title of this post. It has since been updated, which I explained here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/399440/testing-a-new-version-of-stack-overflow-jobs/399442#comment1332911_399442


When thinking about searching for your next technical role, what pieces of information or features would be most useful for you?

The Joel Test Score was pretty great. The answers are what matters to developers, and employers having to fill out this part is a step that acts as a minimal filter to keep job postings in scope. Please make sure to bring it (or something similar) back.

Though I think it would make more sense to allow people to look at the answers (instead of only displaying the score) when expanding or whatever and not just asking e.g. whether they use a VCS but which one etc so that employers don't just tick everything.

Yes that's what I meant, that's how it was shown on StackOverflow Jobs.

It's definitely a bit out of date now though. "Daily builds" is a weird concept. Pretty much you either have CI (build every commit) or you have nothing. "Bug database" would better be called "issue tracker" these days, etc.

@SteveBennett Yes, and "build in one step" should be called "release in one step". Still the list is much better than nothing. Most scores won't be 100% accurate, but the goal really is simplicity not a fine-grained assessment of development process maturity.

Yeah, well those are two different, and valid things I think. It's one thing to be able to, in one step, build a site so that other people in the team/stakeholders etc can access it. Another thing if you can actually roll it out to production in one step. Another thing if you can do that in zero steps (continuous deployment)...!

Thanks for this response! We are keeping track of the feedback on this post and will keep it in mind as we continue to iterate on this feature.

By allowing Indeed to power your listings, you pick up the weaknesses of the platform as well as the capabilities.  I think it's worth listing some of the things that I don't like about how Indeed works:

It doesn't match well on programming language.  It will include listings that use entirely different languages but mention the search term briefly.  Unsurprisingly, employers don't tend to respond well to applications on that basis.
It doesn't limit to the kind of jobs you request.  For example, I'm looking for senior engineer jobs and it keeps showing me jobs with management responsibilities, like tech lead or CTO.
I can't tell it I only want salaried jobs and not hourly jobs.  Only that I want a particular annualized result.
I can't limit my search to only results that allow applications through the platform.  It mixes results that do with ones that require other platforms.  Note that there are three types:  uses Indeed; has its own; uses another job board.
I can't control whether or not I get notified that a particular application has gone into a terminal state.  I don't need a hundred emails telling me that "Hey, we had over a hundred applicants, and we're not interviewing you."  Personally, I would like to see information like that on a polling basis (I look in the job platform to check job status) rather than a push basis (email or other notification).  I only want push notifications for rare things, like interview requests.
I can't filter out employers to whom I already applied.  Yes, I realize that this would cause me to miss out on some opportunities, but it will filter out far more non-opportunities.
It should be easier for employers to include previous applicants in future interview loops.  This should partially compensate for the lost opportunities from the last.

In general, I think that both employers and potential employees would like for there to be fewer but better applications.  Indeed is taking steps to improve that, but they aren't that far along.

Indeed use to a have a feature that made it my favorite site: I could add Comments (to myself) for each job listing. In my case I'd say things like "This is same job as that other post" or "Low paying"  or "Apply immediately!"

I never used the original jobs site but to answer this question:

When thinking about searching for your next technical role, what pieces of information or features would be most useful for you?


Salary (ideally broken down by geographical areas if multiple options are available)
Ability to comment and ask questions about the position (to the poster and to the community)
Ability to rate job openings (up/down vote)
Structured search/filtering on all things like location, remote work, salary, perks, tech stack, travel requirements, on-call, team size etc etc.


"Ability rate job openings" While I think that is an interesting idea, I think votes of SO wouldn't actually tell you something about how good the job is. They would just act as a no-ChatGPT filter.

Interesting ideas! It would be neat to be able to see public conversation about about a job posting between potential applicants and the company - might provide some transparency that is notably missing in the job search today

This is great feedback! We are keeping track of the ideas and suggestions made on this post and will keep them in mind as we continue to iterate on this feature.

As I mentioned in another comment, a personal "Comments" field to remind me of what I thought about the post and what I want to do next

@ShawnV.Wilson If the reminders are only visible to you, that sounds more like Notes than Comments?

@ProphetZarquon Okay, it could have both. They serve different purposes.

Very much agreed

Bringing the SO Jobs is great news. What I wouldn't want to do is to be redirected via 10 links signing up to every platform in the process. It would be good to complete the job application process within SO.
I remember receiving messages directly in Stack Overflow. Also the Developer story would be great to have.

I have much the same gripe with Indeed.  About half the jobs are just links to other platforms.  One of my major complaints is that I can't screen those out of my search results.  If Indeed is "powering" SO Jobs, it is unlikely to offer what you want.

Thanks for this input. I just want to point you to a few of my prior responses that address some of these concerns, in terms of wanting to complete applications within SO, and about the possibility of bringing back dev story.

Tangential to the topic at hand, I'm rather disappointed this got left sidebar space, and chat and meta haven't despite long standing feature requests. As a moderator on a technical site and another one, it’s something that would have potential long term benefits for my site.
Is this going to replace the companies link (which is essentially a vestigial organ of 'old' careers) or is it an added on link without any other changes? (I missed that this was covered in the question)
I see other folks have covered the USPs of old jobs/careers, specifically the developer story, so I won't retread that again. But I suspect that'll have more value for many people.
I used to critique the old SO jobs as something that didn't work because SO was a small fish in the broader job-website market, so I actually think this may be the right way to go if you can combine letting Indeed do the part of building a job site (and ideally at minimal developer work on the SO side) and adding the things that made SO jobs unique on top of that.
You would also do well to remember the main value SO has is their reputation, and preserving that with the community would be a good idea if people were to go with the SO Indeed instance over the main one.
On that note, it feels like you're 'lending' the SO name to a simple rebranded indeed page. I'm pretty sure that the answer I'd get here is 'we can't talk about the financial details', but we just went through a very painful belt tightening process. I'd hope that these 'initiatives' are going to help the bottom line, and that at least some of these resources flow back to the community.

Ugh don't get me started on the Left Nav. It could be so much more, especially on Network sites that really only have 6 links and the "your teams have moved" message :(. Chat, Featured on Meta, Help Center, Review Queues, 10k/Mod tools. All of this should be on Left Nav.

Its one of my two pet peeves, and the simpler one to fix. I'll get started any chance I get ;)

We know that left navigation space is a hot commodity, and we are open to conversations about the best way to utilize it. In this case, we thought it was important to link SO Jobs in a very prominent location on sites because we are testing the potential of this feature, which means giving it a strong chance to be engaged with by many users. The old SO Jobs was also linked from the left navigation so we thought it was a logical choice for this experiment as well.

In addition to creating useful features that add value for users, bringing in more resources that allow us to reinvest in the community, is absolutely one of our goals for partnerships like this one. With more resources we hope to be able to better prioritize feature requests and other improvement asks that come from the community.

@Sasha - You'll have to excuse my hasty mock up - but something like this would be ideal: https://i.sstatic.net/GscF2hmQ.png. Obviously some thought would have to go into who gets to see what links but most of that logic already exists for the links on the top bar. Plus, moving this functionality to the left-nav would allow you to remove it from the top bar, making it a bit cleaner in some contexts (eg mobile)

@Robotnik thanks! I shared that with someone on our UX/UI team.

I miss having my Stack Overflow profile and reputation disconnected from potential employers. I felt that gave some weight to my conversations.

To be honest, I think that SO reputation isn't really a good metric employers should consider.

@dan1st They shouldn't, but they do. When looking for a job (and especially when that isn't by choice - see the large number of layoffs in the tech industry as of late), it's at least nice to be able to take advantage of anything relevant

did you mean to say "connected"?

It ought to be rephrased. Presumably, it is talking about a past where they were connected. And in the future they won't be.

You can always connect your flair to your personal page or something like that. Or add a link to your CV, if you think it this that important.

Rep might not be very relevant but what tags you visit might be. A linked SO profile might save the recruiter from all the "Fizz Buzz" complete incompetence filter work. If someone has made hundreds of posts below the Java tag, they can't be completely oblivious to Java programming. ->

Unlike someone who has Java in their CV because they took a beginner class at one point. If the recruiter has a technical background themselves, it is very easy to see through "Java programming experience" during an interview. And you will get completely oblivious candidates now and then, especially if recruiting fresh-out-of-school.

We appreciate this feedback. I just wanted to point to my response here which addresses this concern.

So... Now that this is live, it's fairly clear that this is just a wrapper of indeed with even less features than indeed has, built by yet another third party (Jobbio). I'm sure over time it'll regain some of the missing features, but will it ever have features that go above and beyond what just going to indeed directly provides? What value would I have in using SO Jobs compared to just going to indeed directly? As it stands now, as an MVP, it probably shouldn't be linked from the side menu. A link to indeed directly would be far more useful to users than this at it's current stage.

What's the decision process for which jobs get listed on the new Stack Overflow Jobs?
As Ian Ringrose explained in their answer, most recruiters not knowing about the old Stack Overflow Jobs was a major advantage.
Is this a checkbox toggled by recruiters, is it automatically determined by Indeed in some way or is it something else? To be honest, I think that if you want this to be actually useful, it should be something that requires explicit opt-in in a way that only looks interesting for people that actually want to have it on Stack Overflow Jobs.

The job listings on Stack Overflow Jobs will all fit within a specific set of titles covering a range of occupations in the technology field, and will all be US-based positions (we may expand to markets outside the US in the future).

Some listings will come from employer’s opted-in to Indeed’s Tech Network, which are sponsored tech jobs. Other listings will simply be relevant jobs (with a matching job title), from any number of employers (we are making sure to include companies of various sizes, alongside more well known tech companies).

If any employer wants their open tech jobs listed on Stack Overflow Jobs they will need to post a job through Indeed’s Tech Network. There will be a link pointing them in that direction on the job site.

So jobs are chosen without requiring opt-in from employers and without anyone reviewing them in any way?


When thinking about searching for your next technical role, what pieces of information or features would be most useful for you?

After experimenting with various job search sites, I'm now using a platform which offers a lot of filters, allowing to have a reasonable signal-to-noise ratio.
Let's look at the things it includes:

type of job (allows me to select "devops", which includes all the different titles that gets included in that category)
location incl remote only
salary
equity
skills I'll get to use in the job
company markets
full time / contract / internship / cofounder
required experience
included keywords
excluded keywords
company size
investment stage
"only show companies that are mostly or fully remote"
"only show companies that can sponsor a visa"

There's also an extensive preferences section that allows me to specify things that adjust whether I show up in companies' searches (this for instance allows me to filter out all cryptocurrency startups).
The end result of these things is that there's enough reduction of noise I can actually spend my human time looking at the results.  That is really the thing I care about, but the most obvious path towards that is gathering all of this structured metadata and allowing us to filter on it - we are programmers and aren't scared of having a bazillion fields at our disposal.  You could even give us a psuedo-SQL interface for querying this, like New Relic does for metrics and Jira does for tickets - but staying simpler than that would still be incredibly useful.  Without some way to filter all these things, though, it's just not worth my time due to the high proportion of job listings that show up in a naive search and aren't interesting to me.

It's a bit unclear what your answer is saying. You seem to be talking about another platform entirely. While that's perfectly reasonable, how does that relate to the announcement here? Could you edit your answer to give details about how this relates to Stack Overflow Jobs?

@Catija   I read this as "Indeed sucks" -- here's how a platform that does not suck should work.  So if Stack is moving to Indeed, it should still allow Stack-like manipulation of the data.  Then it will suck less than Indeed.  The last paragraph is the key.

Very much appreciate this feedback in terms of what is most valuable to you on a job site. I can't make any promises about what functionality will be included in future iterations of SO Jobs, but we  will consider the ideas presented here.

@Catija It is answering the quoted question, which is what Stack Overflow Jobs would need to provide in order for it to be a product I use.  It's a bit more broad than just "Indeed sucks", but rather "all job search sites suck (other than a single one)" and is why I don't use any of the common platforms.  The feedback is essentially that if they build something that is the same as the existing things, I'm not going to use it, but if they build something different, and targeting programmers, they can find their way into a productive niche.

@XiongChiamiov Most especially, that diverse & strictly applied filters, are vitally needed?

As someone who has actually landed a job from SO Careers back in 2016, I would say that the best thing about SO Careers was that it worked.
...unlike certain other sites, whose signal-to-noise ratio is so low, that I cannot really say that they work.

A lot of the value I find in current job listings solutions is the ability to set up a profile with your past experience and future interests and receiving a list that is somewhat relevant to that information. Given this solution is disconnected from your SO profile, would it be filtered by your indeed profile if you had one?
What measures are being taken to ensure offerings are "high quality and highly relevant," particularly in the case of SO where what is relevant to any given person could vary wildly with how broad the set of topics are on SO? Even if you were taking into account our activity on SO to filter jobs... for me that'd be a relatively poor filter, the things I answer questions for aren't really all that relevant for what I actually do on a daily basis or for what I'd be interested in.

Saves me having to post about relevant results. IIRC, under the old search I might search for a keyword combination that actually had no relevant results; rather than be told that, I'd get a load of irrelevant results to sift through - possibly related to additional tags on questions I had answered.

In terms of the possibility of having a user’s SO profile connected to SO Jobs, I would point to my response here.
Regarding the relevance of the job listings, I explained here a bit about where they are coming from.

For now, filtering by location and key words (such as a job title, specific technology, or company name) is the best way for users to find results that are a good fit for them. We hope to expand on this functionality in future iterations of this feature.

@Sasha currently, filtering on location hardly works given you can't filter by state...  Filtering by city is pretty useless if you aren't looking for locations that happen to be highly populated cities. How does only allowing filtering by city even make sense... Have the people designing this never worked outside of a major city? this is ridiculous.
